# How do I wait for a process OR if a certain window becomes the active one in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a loop that waits for a process to exist before continuing. However, I want to make it so that the loop will proceed if EITHER the process exists or a window with some certain class is present. Right now I have the following:

```
Loop {
    Process, Wait, ProcessName.exe
    ; Do stuff

    Sleep, 50
}
```

I want to be clear that I specifically used `Process, Wait` because I didn't want the loop to constantly running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "ProcessName.exe" you can use ["**ahk_exe Process Name/Path**"](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe) to identify the process.
Use "**[DetectHiddenWindows](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DetectHiddenWindows.htm&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiZ6J7gzb3NAhUL3SwKHcbBD9AQFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNG9hwZG8_Y9DqGMz7WX4-96xBzDlw), On**" if there's no visible window of this process.

This way you can create a window group with [**GroupAdd**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm) that contains both the process and the window.
Replace "Process, Wait, ProcessName.exe" with "**WinWait, ahk_group GroupName**" in the loop.

Comment: Do you have any tips for when I want the condition to be if the no-window process exists OR if the window is at the front most of everything?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "if the window is at the front most of everything"? Do you want the script do stuff immediately after the window becomes active ( WinWaitActive), or as soon as it is brought to the top by itself?

Comment: I want to proceed with the `Loop` as soon as `process.exe` is running **or** `ahk_class MyClass` is the current active window `WinActive("ahk_class MyClass")`. So either of those two should allow the `Loop` to continue. They are two separate programs.